# Methods in c# enums

Tags: c#, enums

In Java we can use methods in enums, for example i can write

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(GetNum.TWO.get());
 }

 enum GetNum{
     ONE{
         public int get(){
             return 1;
         }
     },
     TWO{
         public int get(){
             return 2;
         }
     };
     public abstract int get();
 }
```

maybe somebody can say me: in c# enums can I do something like this?

Comment: no, enums are basically ints

Comment: You could achieve something similar with a class and static read-only properties.  But as others have said, its impossible with an enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, but you can sort of though the use of extension methods.

Given an enumeration such as

```
enum HurfDurf
{
    Hurr,
    Durr
}
```

you can create an extension method such as

```
static class HurfDurfExtensions
{
    public static string Wat(this HurfDurf lol)
    {
        return lol == HurfDurf.Hurr ? "Wew lad" : "eyy boss";
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var whatisthisidonteven = HurfDurf.Hurr.Wat();
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. In the background `enum` are value-types (e.g. just an int).

E.g. you can do `int i = (int)yourEnum;`and vice versa.

Comment: Lots of value types can have methods.  That's not the reason you can't define methods for them.  You can even have implicit conversions between `int` and any type (whether a value type or not) so *also* not the reason, nor a property of value types (there are also of course lots of value types *without* any conversions to/from `int`).